# Static Header and First Columns in a Table

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I have a large table, that when scrolling the header and first columns in rows are static and should not move. I would like to solve this with only the CSS. The problem is, that the tables cells are dynamic, so you don’t know what will the width/height be.

```
<table>
   <thead>
        <tr>
        <th>First</th>
        <th>Second</th>
        …
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
        <tr>
            <td class=”static”>First</td>
            <td class=”static”>Second</td>
            <td>4</td>
            <td>5</td>
            <td>6</td>
            <td>7</td>
        …
        </tr>
        ….
    </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: Heres an example: http://jsfiddle.net/jagmitg/te3a4r6h/ Might be what your looking for

Comment: It will not work, because the table scrollable horizontally and vertically, and here the position absolute messes up the header and it is not overflowed correctly.

Comment: I am opened to some plugins, that only do this two things. Performance is really important here.